# Find Curve if locus of centres of spherical curvature is given

Tags: differential-geometry, 3d

Find a curve $\vec{r(s)}^{\,}$ with arc length parameter $s$ whose locus of centers of spherical curvature is
$\vec{r^{*}(s)}^{\,} = (cos s, sin s, s).$

I tried using the result that product of corresponding torsions and radii of curvature are equal. But I couldn't reach anywhere. Please if anybody could give me any idea, it will be helpful. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't know the result to which you refer. Do you know about involutes and evolutes?

Comment: Yes I know about evolutes and involutes

Comment: I retract the question. I was thinking of the osculating circle, not sphere. What result about torsion and curvature are you referring to?

Comment: product of torsion of original curve and its locus of centers of spherical curvature= product of curvature of both

Comment: I've never seen that before. Proof? So since the helix has constant curvature and torsion, the original curve must be a generalized helix.

Comment: Yeah I reached there. But I couldn't solve the constants after taking a generalised helix. What equations should I use?

Comment: I would work with the Frenet frame of the unknown curve, write down from it a parametrization of the loci of centers of spherical curvature and derive conditions for whatever the constant curvature and torsion are.

Comment: Having worked on it a bit, I think your result is misquoted. These curves will have to be Bertrand mates, and so the torsions at corresponding points will have constant product.

Comment: Ah, my result is a bit stronger than yours. Presumably someone proved the curves were Bertrand mates to show that.